# Django - ChoiceField without using forms.py file

Tags: django

I’m trying to use a choice field in Django views.py
I don’t have the forms.py in this folder.
what should i do?
models,py

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Unclassified')

class Category(models.Model): 
     Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Unclassified')
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = [
         "category",
]
```

Comment: why don't you add a form.py

Comment: also doesn't django allow you to create a button from models.Model and assign the click to a function in which you can write a specific function to get the info from the charfield and then just evaluate there then send it back to the user ?

Comment: why can I just add the function  into views.py instead forms.py? and just like you said make the choice button from there

Comment: What I was saying was if you don't want forms.py then in your main script(views.py) then you create all the necessary things including a button there and you just have a function that will run on the click event of the button

Comment: although forms.py was made so that you can implement forms in a more organized way but doesn't mean you have to necessarily use them

Comment: I'm using as_crispy_field, thats why I don't need a forms.py, but now I did in the views.py the function but it didn't work. I have two class (Post and Category) but in the views.py when I add a function for Post it works well but when I add the Category it stop. I tried to make another function for the Category but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work on updating the model field and making migrations then migrating it.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

refer [django_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).